# How to use value of std::string as pattern for Flex rule?

Tags: c++, gnu, flex-lexer

Is is possible to use a std::string as pattern for a rule in Flex??

Example:

```
%{
...
string foo
...
%}
...
%%
foo {}
%%
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least if I understand what you're asking, the answer is no.

The patterns specified for a Flex scanner need to be constants -- i.e., when Flex runs, it converts them into a state machine. The code it produces is primarily a set of tables for the state machine. To do that, all the strings/patterns involved must be known when Flex itself runs.

As an aside, there's really no such thing as GNU Flex. Flex is not GNU software.